# After posting backend responding a token . Now how will get that that token? flutter http request

Tags: flutter, http, dart, http-post, flutter-http

After log in backend responding a token. Now how will get that that token?

I used HTTP package for this project. I am new to flutter.  my code example:

```
  Future<void> login() async {
if (_password.text.isNotEmpty && _number.text.isNotEmpty) {
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(
        'https://api.azabazar.com/api/login/?fbclid=IwAR2Sz4ky31HCG4g2Sbhn08LV3QqV76YEaIIQwpRavXRB1A4o0fq4aiQ22kE'),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Basic your_api_token_here', //here i want my token
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
      "username": _number.text,
      "password": _password.text,
    }),
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 201) {
    const Text("Loged in");
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to find account.');
  }
} else {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
      .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("invalid form")));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you've got something like this from server:

```
{
  "data": {
    "token": "TOKEN"
    ...
  }
}
```

You can get the token like this:

```
if (response.statusCode == 201) {
  final decodedResponse = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map;
  final token = decodedResponse['data']['token'];
} else {
  throw Exception('Failed to find account.');
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Btw how can I save that token?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences can be an option. @Romanchhaque